# How to send HTTPClient post message with certain interval

Tags: java, post, httpclient

I want to send http post message to the client (which i can do without any problem). 
But I want to send this message continously. Say for instance every 5 mintutes I want to send this message to client. Is there any way to do that? 
thanks in advance..

Comment: Your question is vague. What do you mean by HTTP post message? How are you currently doing this and what technology are you using?

Comment: I am doing with apache commonHTTPClient. Like in http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html example. But this sends one http post but i want to keep on sending http posts without getting any acknowledgement.

Comment: What's your environment like? Simple standalone app? Then maybe a simple java.util.Timer woudl do the job. Or maybe you need a more andvanced Quartz scheduler? Is it a JavaEE app? Then perhaps you need an EJB timer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It was a JEE app. I used EJBtimer as  @DagR suggested. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the easiest way is to use a *ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor* (attention, the following code will never exit):

```
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your request code here

        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```